# Filter GWCODE categories by entry count

Tags: plugins, expressionengine, categories

I am using the GWCODE categories plugin for my sidebar in ExpressionEngine.

Is there a way to only show children (depth_2) categories that have 15 or more entries? I know there a entry_count variable, but I am not certain how to use it in order to filter the output

Answer (score 0):

When using the entry_count variable ensure you specify it as a parameter, otherwise it won't output anything.

```
{exp:gwcode_categories channel="example" depth="2" entry_count="yes"}
    {if {depth} == 2 && {entry_count} >= 15}
        {cat_name}
    {/if}
{/exp:gwcode_categories}
```

If you specify/clarify the code you're currently using I can refine the example above.